# Not stopping the process with (Ctrl + C) while using asyncio.gather

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, pyrogram

When I use `asyncio.gather` to run two asynchronous functions, one of which is infinite, the program does not stop with <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

One of them is idle related to pyrogram and the other is an endless function.

I tried many methods, but none of them worked.

The code:

```py
from pyrogram.methods.utilities.idle import idle
from pyrogram.client import Client

from asyncio import sleep, run, gather

bot = Client(...)

async def time_checker():
    while True:
        print("I am still here !")
        # await ...
        await sleep(10)

async def main():
    await bot.start()
    await gather(idle(), time_checker())
    await bot.stop()

run(main())
```

I tried try-except, signal.SIGINT, bot.is_connected and ...

I want both functions to run forever, but when <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> is used, the process will stop